# Save the array returned by Javascript Map function to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects. I want to have a new array that contains the same elements but only their `x` property.

So the original array is:

```
[{x: "401K", y:1000}, {x: "RSU": y: 6000}]
```

And the new array would be:

```
["401k", "RSU"]
```

I have tried:

```
const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)
```

When I pass `this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x))` to `console.log` in the call back function of `setstate`, it prints the correct array. But when I `console.log(this.state.pieLegend)` () its an empty array.

```
  computeTotals(){
    var runningTotal = 0
    var pieArray = []
    var beyondBudget = {}

  const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)
  console.log("this does not show correct array", legend)
    //filter out all $0 answers
    Object.keys(this.state.data.selectedQuestions)
  .filter(key => Object.values(this.state.data.selectedQuestions[key])[0] != 0)
  .map((key, index) => {
    const value = Object.values(this.state.data.selectedQuestions[key])[0]
    const name = key
    runningTotal += value
    //still not gone beyond budget, add to pie chart
    if(runningTotal <= 1600){
      let pieSlice =
           {
             x: name,
             y: value
           };
      pieArray = pieArray.concat(pieSlice)

    }
    //went beyond budget, add to beyondbudget table data
    else {

          if (Object.keys(beyondBudget).length == 0) {
              beyondBudget[name] = {};
              beyondBudget[name] = runningTotal - 1600;
              let pieSlice =
                   {
                     x: name,
                     y: value - (beyondBudget[name])
                   };
              pieArray = pieArray.concat(pieSlice)
          }
          if (!beyondBudget[name]) {
              beyondBudget[name] = {};
          }
          if (Object.keys(beyondBudget).length > 1) {
              beyondBudget[name] = value;
          }

      }
  })

    this.setState({
      pieChartData: pieArray,
      total: runningTotal,
      beyondBudget: beyondBudget,
      pieLegend: this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)
    }, () => {
      console.log("this shows correct array",  this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x));
      console.log("this does not", this.state.pieLegend)
      this.computePiePercentages();

    });

}
```

I thought the issue was that I'm not returning anything. So I tried this:

```
const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(function justName(item){
      console.log("test!")
      return item.x
    }
```

But my test statement did not event print.

Comment: is `[{x: "401K", y:1000}, {"RSU": 6000}]` right? One has an `x` and `y`, but the second item does not have those keys. Other than that, it should work exactly like you expect it to.

Comment: good catch - edited to depict the array correctly

Comment: You have an extra parentheses in `const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x))`

Comment: I do (did - edited my post after your catch)! but not in my code

Comment: Is the `console.log(legend)` in the same function as its declaration `const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)`

Comment: If it works when you console.log the map, but not when you console.log(legend), then there's a difference between the two calls, otherwise the first would not work.

Comment: Did you accidentally declare legend as `const` before doing `const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)`? This ought to throw errors, but maybe in your environment or whatever it's just refusing to reassign the value.

Comment: @Mordred You're right - the `console.log(this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x))` only works in the callback of `setState`. But `console.log(this.state.pieLegend)` inside same callback prints empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown, your `setState` method will not work correctly:

```
    this.setState({
      pieChartData: pieArray,
      total: runningTotal,
      beyondBudget: beyondBudget,
      pieLegend: this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)
    }, () => {});
```

You are setting `pieLegend` to `this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)` at the same time you're setting `pieChartData`. But because it's at the same time (and is presumably doing an `Object.assign()` internally), the value of pieChartData is still undefined when `this.state.pieChartData.map(a => a.x)` is evaluated, and therefore state.pieLegend will also be undefined.

You'll need to set pieChartData first before attempting to map over it, or just map over pieArray to begin with:

```
this.setState({
    pieChartData: pieArray,
    total: runningTotal,
    beyondBudget: beyondBudget,
    pieLegend: pieArray.map(a => a.x)
}, () => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine...

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
  pieChartData: [{ x: '401K', y: 1000 }, { x: 'RSU', y: 6000 }],
 };

 render() {
  const legend = this.state.pieChartData.map(val => val.x);
  console.log(legend);
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>{JSON.stringify(legend)}</h1>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: does it make a difference that this is happening in render and mine is not?